# Angularjs controller - non-trivial initial state

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am just starting with `angular.js` and today when I was writing my controller:

```
myApp.controller('RepetitionController', ['$scope', '$location', 'repetitionService',
    function ($scope, $location, repetitionService) {



        $scope.questions = repetitionService.getQuestions();
        $scope.questionsLeft = $scope.questions.length;
        $scope.questionsAnswered = 0;
        $scope.percentageLeft = ($scope.questionsLeft == 0 ? 100 : 0);
        $scope.repetitonState = ??? 
        $scope.endRepetition = function () {
            repetitionService.clearSelectedSets();
            $location.path("/setsAndCollections");
        }

        $scope.submitAnswer = function () {
            alert("alert");
        }
    }]);
```

I started to wonder.

You can see I used ternary operator to create initial state of `$scope`, now in my `repetitionState` field I want something like this `(questionsLeft === 0 ? 'finished' : questions[0].type)`.

Is there any way I could define a function that will be invoked after populating `$scope` object, some kind of post-constructor?

Or maybe there is a way to "watch" on functions, so I could write

```
$scope.repetitionState = function(){
    ///logic here
};
```

I am just worried that there would be situations where I would need to write `logicalExpression ? anonymousFunction () : someOtherAnonymousFunction()`, and for me, nesting all those anonymous functions is (for now) a bit hard to read and I wanted to know if there is some part of `angular` that could be useful in this kind of situations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can most certainly watch a function. `$watch` accepts either a string or a function for it the watchExpression parameter. If you are using a function, the current scope is passed to that function as the first argument.

An important thing to remember is that the watchExpression function should be idempotent, so make sure you only update the scope in the listener function.

```
$scope.repititionState = getRepititionState($scope);

$scope.$watch(getRepititionState, function(newVal, oldVal, scope) {
    scope.renditionState = newVal;
});

function getRepititionState(scope) {
    var repititionState;
    // your logic here, just remember to set and return repititionState
    return repititionState;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This will come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you want to reference that `repititionState` why dont you reference it as a function?

For example : Let us assume that you are going to use `repititionState` to get you the class as below

```
<div ng-class="repititionState"></div>

$scope.repititionState = ($scope.questionsLeft === 0 ? 'finished' : $scope.questions[0].type)
```

So that whenever your question is finished that div gets a class of `finished`. In order to make this `repititionState` depend on another variable ( like the way you want it ) its as simple as making it a function.

```
<div ng-class="repititionState()"></div>
```

Notice the extra `()` which marks the `repititionState` as a function now.

```
$scope.repititionState = function(){
    return ($scope.questionsLeft === 0 ? 'finished' : $scope.questions[0].type);
}
```

If you are inside of an `ng-repeat` then you could even pass the `$index` to make this function more generic.

```
$scope.repititionState = function($index){
return ($scope.questionsLeft === 0 ? 'finished' : $scope.questions[$index].type);
}
```

This is commonly called as a computed property in other frameworks. In Angular it is just a function. Hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't think this would be so simple, I fought I could just reference normal values and change them by using functions in my controller, thanks.